# Google Docs Api v3 upload zip permissions

Tags: php, google-data-api

According to the [docs](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UploadingFiles) any file type can now be uploaded to Google Docs, however my upload script always returns:

> 403 You do not have permission to perform this operation.

It works fine with plain text documents and version 1 (not 3 as below). I'm trying to upload a tar.gz with mime type "application/x-gzip". I have a feeling it's the mime that's kicking it out. I also have the convert parameter set to false.

I'm using Zend Framework to do this but setting the version (GET parameter v) to 3 (1 won't let this work).

This is the code, very simple:

```
    $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(self::USER, self::PASS, Zend_Gdata_Docs::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME);
    $docs = new Zend_Gdata_Docs($client);
    $result = $docs->uploadFile($latest,
                        'Backup: '.$filename,
                        'application/x-gzip',
                        'https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full?v=3&convert=false');
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you need to use an resumable upload link, as this is the only one to support any file type.

http://code.google.com/apis/documents/forum.html?place=topic%2Fgoogle-documents-list-api%2FMdfqFMS4yHI%2Fdiscussion

If anyone needs help:
http://www.needathinkle.com/tumblr/view/6431275496